# tkinter start and stop buttons

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

ive done two opc-ua servers one that reads the tag value from a textfile and another that reads the value from SQL. Now ive done a "server menu" in tkinter that can start the servers among other things.
The problem is that i cant turn one of them off and leave the other one running,
i want something like this:

```
import subprocess

def start_txt():
    txt = subprocess.Popen("python TAG_TXT.py &", shell=True)
    return txt

def stop_txt():
     subprocess.Popen('taskkill /F /PID {0}'.format(start_txt(txt)),
                                                         shell=True)

def start_SQL():
    SQL = subprocess.Popen("python TAG_SQL.py &", shell=True)
    return SQL

def stop_SQL():
    subprocess.Popen('taskkill /F /PID {0}'.format(start_SQL(txt)), 
                                                        shell=True)
```

if i use this:

```
os.system("taskkill /f /im python.exe")
```

i kill both servers

error msg:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\PY_OPCUA\servermeny_GUI.py", line 237, in kill_txt
    subprocess.Popen('taskkill /F /PID {0}'.format(textfile_server(txt)), 
                                                              shell=True)
NameError: name 'txt' is not defined
```

ive only used tkinter once before so it is probably very easy fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined txt.
 
In your stop functions you call:

```
subprocess.Popen('taskkill /F /PID {0}'.format(start_SQL(txt)), shell=True)
```

**txt** has not been defined before, I guess you forgot to add it as a function parameter

Comment: sorry i suck at functions, should i have txt parameter in stop or start function?

Comment: You should have txt parameter in any function that directly uses it